# Как убрать отступы с краёв страницы у footer?

Tags: html, css, html5, веб-программирование

Не могу понять откуда образовались в div блоке эти отступы, в css заданы 0 на отступах и с другими блоками проблем нет, как их убрать?

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #444;

}
```

Вот код footer если необходим и его свойства в css

```
<div class="footer">
    <table class="footer">
        <!-- Footer -->
        <tr>
            <td valign=top>
                <div id="footer">
                    <p>&copy; 2023 Частичное или полное копирование информации с данного сайта для распространения на
                        других
                        ресурсах, в том числе и бумажных, строго запрещено.</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
#footer {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.82);;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fdc073;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Само фото]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так а зачем в table засунули его?
По моему этого вполне хватает для Футера

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>&copy; 2023 Частичное или полное копирование информации с данного сайта для распространения на других  ресурсах, в том числе и бумажных, строго запрещено.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! И правда конструкция была лишней! Я в фронтенде ноль полный, но для первого беккенд проекта на Django без верстки, к сожалению, не обойтись